# How can I do to use .env file with environment variables in Angular2 application?

Tags: angular, environment-variables

I usually use the `dotenv`package for manage `.env` files and environment variables. How can I do to use this package within my Angular2 application?

I imported the `dotenv` but I got several errors.

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv' //alternatively import {} from 'dotenv/config';

dotenv.config(); //initialize them
```

When I try to use any `process.env` environment variable it doesn't work.

If I use in the server part of the application I have not errors requiring this package.

Note. I have added the @types/dotenv dependency without success.

Comment: JavaScript applications, running in the browser, don't have access to environment variables.

Comment: Yes @JBNizet, I know, but if it is rendered in the server-side? Or if I need to take some API tokens without show them in the browser? Maybe a services to get those through an API served with node.js?

Comment: Yes, you can of course get data from the server using HTTP. But make sure to understand that an API key, whether it's embedded into the JavaScript code of you angular app, or downloaded from the server by the application, will be available to a user of your app.

Comment: What is your recommendation then to manage API_SECRETS and other vars used by i.e an JWT AUTH0 Angular2 application, what is my case?

Comment: If data must be kept secret from the user of your app, then keep it on the server.

Comment: Use [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it working with `dotenv` with low effort. Instead, I added `/src/environments/` to my .env file. This way all content in the environment folder won't be uploaded to your repository. Maybe this will do it for you, even if the `dotenv` solution would be nicer.